# Is there a way to pass a role json file to the chef-run utility in chef-workstation?

Tags: chef

The chef-run executable provided in chef workstation allows you to run adhoc configuration tasks. The documentation also states that you can run commands, recipes and even cookbooks on remote machines using the chef-run tool.
Is it possible to use chef-run and pass a role json file and will it get applied to the remote node?